# GIT: push different subdirectories to different remote repositories

Tags: git, bitbucket

In my GIT implementation, all changes are pulled from, and pushed to one remote `origin`. I also have just one local branch: `master`.

I have clients that clone and pull from `origin`. However, they only need certain folders. Pulling everything each time will overwrite some folders which is not desired. Git doesn't seem to allow selective pulling.

I've created another remote repo: `production`; where only certain folders from my local repository will be pushed. The expected outcome is that `origin` contains all folders of the project, while `production` contains just some selected folders.

I'll be glad to get hints or an alternative minimal approach to resolve this.

**Here's an example to illustrate:**
My local repository has the following structure:

```
root/...
root/folder1...
root/folder2...
root/folder3...
root/folder4...
```

I initialized git in the root folder, and I track and push all changes to my remote `origin`. Clients pulling from `origin` get all changes from folders1-4. However, they only need say folder2 and folder4. So my idea is to continue pushing all commits to `origin`, but be able to push only commits on folder2 and folder4 to `production`.

That way, if a client clones origin, they'll get folders1-4. If they clone `production`, they get just folder2 and folder4.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Git does not push files or folders, it works in terms of *commits*. If you want to send commits that contain subsets of other commits, you must make separate commits of those subsets. After that, you can push whichever subgraphs you like to whichever remotes you like.

Comment: Hi from 2020. Have you solved it? I want to push `project` to origin, but front and backend to separate production remotes. Is it possible? [Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Comment: @Denis Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42691835/5784831 solve your problem? See below...

Comment: Thanks @Christoph, but no, I want to push `root` with all children to `origin`, but `child1` to frontend prod, and `child2` to backend prod

Comment: @Denis I thought about the same, but I just realized, it is a bad idea. So I will switch to the method below. There is no drawback.

Answer (score 3):

if you have projects that cannot pull the entire repository then you have setup the wrong structure.

You need to setup a repository for each component that each 'project' requires, that way they can use the repository properly for each separate part.

If this still doesnt suit, then Id suggest that your overall architecture needs looking at.

Answer (score 1):

In such case, I keep two git repositories. There are more proper ways to do this, but this approach works too. If the directories are as follows, then,

```
root/...
root/prod/....
```

Now you can do `git init` on `root` directory here. and add this `prod` to the `.gitignore` file. Then `git init` on `root/prod` and treat this as a completely different repository.

If you don't add `prod` to `.gitignore` file, you can track it on the first repository.

Comment: Hi. Using your analogy, the local directories are of the form: root/..., root/folder1..., root/folder2..., root/folder3.... At the moment, I track and push all changes on root (which includes folders1,2,3) to origin. I want to push only changes on say folder1 and folder3 to prod remote repository. That way, if someone clones origin, they get the entire project, and if they clone prod, they get only folder1 and folder3 each time. Thanks.